# SDL1 and CLion. Where do I begin?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I'm moving from MS Visual Studio to JetBrains' CLion, and I'm trying to setup a extremely simple SDL project, but can't get it to build. I'm not using SDL2, but an older version of SDL, as it's required for this project.

What I have so far are these two files: *main.cpp* and *CMakeLists.txt*, whose contents I'm pasting below.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(simple_project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(simple_project ${SOURCE_FILES})

include_directories(simple_project PRIVATE "C:/SDL/include")
target_link_libraries(simple_project "C:/SDL/lib/SDL.lib" "C:/temp/jogos/SDL/lib/SDLmain.lib")
```

So I'm getting the following error:

```
c:/win-builds/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x25): undefined reference to `WinMain'
```

I'm completely newbie with CMake and MinGW, so I have no idea of what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

add to the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL

Comment: Now the error changed to "cannot find -lSDLmain" and "cannot find -lSDL" - http://pastebin.com/kA9tKEEz

Comment: and if you try #include "sdl/SDL.h" ?

Comment: Then it yields a fatal error:
`C:\Users\Charles\ClionProjects\simple-project\main.cpp:1:21: fatal error: sdl/SDL.h: No such file or directory`